# Pass Prisma transaction into a function in typescript

Tags: typescript, transactions, prisma, typing

Hi I have following issue. I have prisma transaction but I would like to pass the prisma transaction client into a function like this:

```js
...
prisma.$transaction(async (tx) => {
  someFunction(tx)
})
...

function someFunction(tx: WHATTOTYPEHERE){
}
```

However I am doing it in typescript and I don't want to use type ANY. But i dont know how  to type the interactive transactin prisma client... the "WHATTOTYPEHERE" type for it.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type in the (EDIT: formerly) accepted answer is no longer correct in the latest version of Prisma.

As a more future-proof type, you can use the `Parameters` type helper to extract the type from the `$transaction` method itself.

This will work even if the transaction type changes *as long as* the `$transaction's` method signature stays the same.

```
import { PrismaClient } from "@prisma/client";

export type PrismaTransactionalClient = Parameters<
    Parameters<PrismaClient['$transaction']>[0]
>[0];
```

Answer (score 2):

If you peeked the definition of `$transaction`, you would find this:

```
$transaction<R>(fn: (prisma: Omit<this, "$connect" | "$disconnect" | "$on" | "$transaction" | "$use">) => Promise<R>, options?: { maxWait?: number, timeout?: number }): Promise<R>
```

Copy/paste that definition and write your own type for use:

```
import { PrismaClient } from "@prisma/client";

type PrismaTransactionClient = Omit<PrismaClient, "$connect" | "$disconnect" | "$on" | "$transaction" | "$use">

function someFunction(tx: PrismaTransactionClient){
// code here
}
```